# How to set each perl script's perl path for a conda build

Tags: perl, conda

I've been banging my head against this for awhile now and I need some help.  I have a nice little perl package I developed.  Works great.  It has a simple install procedure:

```
perl makefile.PL
make
make install
```

I've been trying to write my first ever conda recipe so that I can eventually use it to create a package on galaxy that automatically installs via bioconda.

The problem is that the procedure above isn't enough for a conda build.sh script and I don't know how to make the shebang line of the installed perl script have the correct perl path.  I first tried this:

```
perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=${PREFIX} INSTALLDIRS=site
make
make install
```

based on stuff I've seen in other recipes, but this results in an error:

```
/Users/rleach/local/miniconda3/conda-bld/vcfsamplecompare_1538773699290/test_tmp/run_test.sh: /Users/rleach/local/miniconda3/conda-bld/vcfsamplecompare_1538773699290/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pla/bin/vcfSampleCompare.pl: /Users/rleach/local/miniconda3/conda-bld/vcfsamplecompare_1538773699290/_build: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
Tests failed for vcfsamplecompare-v2.005-pl526_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to /Users/rleach/local/miniconda3/conda-bld/broken
```

I noticed in the build output a note like this:

```
Renaming build prefix directory,  /Users/rleach/local/miniconda3/conda-bld/vcfsamplecompare_1538773699290/_build_env  to  /Users/rleach/local/miniconda3/conda-bld/vcfsamplecompare_1538773699290/build_prefix_moved_vcfsamplecompare-v2.005-pl526_0_osx-64
```

So on a hunch, I added this after my `make install`:

```
sed -i.bak 's|_build_env|build_prefix_moved_vcfsamplecompare-v2.005-pl526_0_osx-64|g' ${PREFIX}/bin/vcfSampleCompare.pl
```

And that worked!  (Anyway, it got me past the first error - now it complains about the module it was also supposed to install not being in @INC.  - one thing at a time though...)

The problem is, I don't know where to find the string "build_prefix_moved_vcfsamplecompare-v2.005-pl526_0_osx-64".  It's obviously going to be different on different systems.  If I assume that "build_prefix_moved_" is static, I know which environment variables will give me "vcfsamplecompare", "v2.005", and "64" (maybe even "osx") - but I cannot find anything that has the value "pl526_0", so I don't seem to have the ability to fully build the string on my own...

So what's the conventional wisdom here?  How should I be setting the perl interpreter path at the top of the scripts in the package?

Comment: ExtUtils::MakeMaker will rewrite the shebang of each script it installs to the perl interpreter you run Makefile.PL with. But note there is a [bug](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/issues/58) where it won't do this if the shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env perl` (which is otherwise recommended for non-installed scripts). I don't know anything about conda and can't quite figure out what this build process has to do with the location of the Perl interpreter for the shebang.

Comment: Cona creates an environment for each build that can be loaded/unloaded (similar to the module command). Perl is installed in the environment too so as to be independent from other environments. Thus, I need to know where that perl interpreter is going to go so that the shebang is correct. Even if I put an env on the shebang, to be conda-correct, I would have to use the env command that's in the independent environment for the install.

Comment: Can you run the installation with that perl interpreter after it's in the correct location? This would rewrite the shebang correctly.

Comment: I think you’re right. I had thought that any command (e.g. env) would have to be specific to the environment, but someone else on bioconda recommended the same thing. So I’ll use it. I’m sure it will work. This is my first Conda recipe. I just wanted to make sure I was doing it correctly.

Comment: So using `#!/usr/bin/env perl` at the top of the script allows the script to run without the interpreter error, but the next error is that it can't find the module in @INC that's also installed as a part of the package...

Comment: As mentioned `#!/usr/bin/env perl` will not be rewritten as part of the installation process. This also means that after installation, it will use whatever perl is first in the user's PATH, not necessarily the one it (+dependencies) was installed to.

Comment: Right... I understand that.  The module is installed with the script though.  It comes with it.  Conda is moving things around though (if I understand it correctly).  Outside of conda, that's not a problem.  `make install` puts the module somewhere in @INC.  But in conda, I can tell `perl Makefile.PL` where to put the module with things like `INSTALLDIRS=site INSTALL_BASE=$PREFIX`, but the entire `@INC` array in the error doesn't include the path where it put the module. The "PREFIX" part is different. Seems like the same deal as where the script went vs the shebang...

Comment: Conda tells me where it's putting the module: `Installing /opt/conda/conda-bld/vcfsamplecompare_1539033227804/_build_env/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/CommandLineInterface.pm`, but the @INC in the test from `meta.yaml` is different: `@INC contains: /opt/conda/conda-bld/vcfsamplecompare_1539033227804/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pla/lib/site_perl/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /opt/conda/conda-bld/vcfsamplecompare_1539033227804/_...`

Comment: Conda is installing perl as a part of the conda recipe. It should (ostensibly) be the first perl in the path, so I don't know why the module is ending up installed elsewhere... As I understand it, @INC is populated at the time perl is compiled and it's obviously being created during the vcfsamplecompare installation because the paths in @INC include the package name I'm installing. Conda told me that it installed the module - but why is `_build_env` different from the ridiculously long `_test_env_placehold_...` component of the path?

Comment: A colleague of mine figured it out. I had included perl under both the build & host sections under requirements in the meta.yaml file. It was not clear to me from the doc that this wasn't what you should do. In fact, I had used the meta.yaml file from another recipe as a template, so when it was recommended I should have perl under the 'host' section, I added it, but it didn't occur to me that it should then be removed from 'build'. After all, I was calling perl in the build script & the doc says to have stuff there you need for the build... Such an easy solution, but invisible to a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had suspected, you shouldn't have to provide `INSTALL_BASE=${PREFIX}` or even `PREFIX=${PREFIX}` to Makefile.PL in order for it to work.  The fact that the script being found on the PATH has the wrong perl interpreter path suggests that there may be some compiled version of perl that is available when running the script which is different from the one that was used when building the script.  This is consistent with the issue with the different paths in `@INC`.

It turned out that the `meta.yaml` file had perl in 2 places: under `requirements:build:` and `requirements:host:` and thus 2 different versions of perl were in use during the build versus running on the host.  By removing the one under `requirements:build:` in the meta.yaml file, there's only 1 version of perl and the conflict is resolved.  All that's needed in the build.sh file is:

```
perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site
make
make install
```

Just be sure that the meta.yaml has:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - make
  host:
    - perl
  run:
    - perl
```

It may be tempting to put `perl` under the build section because you're using a call to perl in the build.sh script, but it's there on the host when the build is done.